# BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION structure - Microsoft Office Files

Tags: ms-office, structure

The BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION structure is supposed to remain unique even after editing a file.  When I tested this on a text file it worked fine, yet when it was tested on a docx and a xlsx file it seemed to change.  Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the declaration of BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION

```
public struct BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION
{
    public uint FileAttributes;
    public FILETIME CreationTime;
    public FILETIME LastAccessTime;
    public FILETIME LastWriteTime;
    public uint VolumeSerialNumber;
    public uint FileSizeHigh;
    public uint FileSizeLow;
    public uint NumberOfLinks;
    public uint FileIndexHigh;
    public uint FileIndexLow;
}
```

As you can see it contains some size information, last access time... Therefore I don't see how this could stay unique.

But there are 2 fields which remain unique (even if you move the file (on the same disk)) `FileIndexHigh` and `FileIndexLow`